# How to get AWS VCPU's utilization number via API

Tags: amazon-web-services, vcpu

I would like to get the number of AWS VCPU's used by all running instances in the region via GO API, so I can run some preflight checks before I create new instances, to see if there are enough VCPU's available, without increasing the quota.

In other words, if we look at the console we can see that **Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances** service quota, shows **Applied quota value** column that indicates the current VCPU's limit. If you click on this field, you can see the 'Utilization' field that shows the used VCPU's. This is what I need.

[image: AWS Service Quotas - Running On-Demand Standard instances]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have perhaps a screenshot of what you are after? Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 1):

To discover where this information was available, I looked into the **Service Quotas** AWS service.

The `aws service-quotas list-service` command lists the **service codes**, such as:

```json
{
    "Services": [
        {
            "ServiceCode": "AWSCloudMap",
            "ServiceName": "AWS Cloud Map"
        },
        ...
        {
            "ServiceCode": "ec2",
            "ServiceName": "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)"
        },
        ...
        {
            "ServiceCode": "xray",
            "ServiceName": "AWS X-Ray"
        }
    ]
}
```

So, the service code for Amazon EC2 is `ec2`.

Next, I listed the quotas for this service using `aws service-quotas list-service-quotas --service-code ec2`. Amongst the output I found:

```json
{
    "Quotas": [
    ...
        {
            "ServiceCode": "ec2",
            "ServiceName": "Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (Amazon EC2)",
            "QuotaArn": "arn:aws:servicequotas:ap-southeast-2:123456789012:ec2/L-1216C47A",
            "QuotaCode": "L-1216C47A",
            "QuotaName": "Running On-Demand Standard (A, C, D, H, I, M, R, T, Z) instances",
            "Value": 640.0,
            "Unit": "None",
            "Adjustable": true,
            "GlobalQuota": false,
            "UsageMetric": {
                "MetricNamespace": "AWS/Usage",
                "MetricName": "ResourceCount",
                "MetricDimensions": {
                    "Class": "Standard/OnDemand",
                    "Resource": "vCPU",
                    "Service": "EC2",
                    "Type": "Resource"
                },
                "MetricStatisticRecommendation": "Maximum"
            }
        },

    ...
    ]
}
```

This seemed to match the quota displayed in the Management Console.

I then noticed that the `UsageMetric` information looked like an Amazon CloudWatch metric:

```json
            "UsageMetric": {
                "MetricNamespace": "AWS/Usage",
                "MetricName": "ResourceCount",
                "MetricDimensions": {
                    "Class": "Standard/OnDemand",
                    "Resource": "vCPU",
                    "Service": "EC2",
                    "Type": "Resource"
                },
                "MetricStatisticRecommendation": "Maximum"
            }
```

I then went to Amazon CloudWatch, clicked **All metrics** and entered a search term of `usage standard`:

[image: Amazon CloudWatch metrics search]

Aha! The `Standard/OnDemand` metric appeared!

Selecting the checkbox then showed a chart:

[image: Amazon CloudWatch metrics chart]

This metric matches the `Utilization` figure shown in the **Service Quotas** page.

**Bottom line**

**Service Quota metrics** are available through Amazon CloudWatch. You can use standard API calls to retrieve these metrics, or access them through the Amazon CloudWatch Metrics management console. You can also **Create Alarms** on these metrics to notify you when they exceed desired limits.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer John. I found this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html and the value I need is the 'ResourceCount'. I tried to use 'awsClient.cloudwatch.GetMetricData()' but that won't help. If you can point me to the api call to fetches the ResourceCount by passing the service name, type,resource class as mentioned in the link above, that would be great.

Comment: This is a better one: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/viewing_metrics_with_cloudwatch.html#service-quota-metrics

Comment: So I can do this in my code:                            listMetricsInput :=  cloudwatch.ListMetricsInput{ Dimensions: dimentsions, MetricName: &metricName} ;                                                                       
metricsData, err := client.cloudwatchClient.ListMetrics(ctx, &listMetricsInput) where the dimensions include the right input. This find my metric !! But I still do not see how do I get the ResourceCount.

Comment: I also tried MetricDataQuery but did not get values in the response.

Comment: I was able to retrieve the metrics with: `aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --metric-name ResourceCount --start-time 2022-03-20T00:00:00 --end-time 2022-03-25T00:00:00 --period 86400 --namespace AWS/Usage --statistics Maximum --dimensions Name=Service,Value=EC2 Name=Type,Value=Resource Name=Resource,Value=vCPU Name=Class,Value=Standard/OnDemand` (I found that it required _all_ of those Dimensions to return a result.)

Comment: You are the best !! Thank you so much. One last question - Since I need the current maximum resource count, I set the endTime to Now(), and the startTime to Now() - 5 minutes. If I set the the startTime less then 5 minutes, I do not get the result. Is that expected? It does not let me set the startTime to Now() of course. It returns error.

Comment: The metrics probably only update every hour or so. Just set a longer time period and always use `Maximum` to discover the biggest value it was recently.